# 2014 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2014 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://superuser.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Is it true that there is only 1 moderator position?  WHY, I see multiple deserving canidates, that have been great help to the site and I assume would still be a great asset to the community as moderators.  Does anyone know a single reason why too many of these great cooks would spoil this broth?

Comment: @Psycogeek there are 2 positions available and many moderation tools are available at different reputation levels for users as they progress on the site. That being said, I don't think your question is any *less* valid.

Comment: Ahh, I see now from reading and re-reading it, that they were indicating that a favored candidate, who would get thier first vote, would leave only 1 more slot available. 
 Making me as guilty of not having fully read and comprehended what was being said, before assuming.

Comment: Currently taking bribes for my vote.

Comment: @Sickest  just vote on your answers or what?